# Property-like closures for local variables

Tags: ios, swift, closures

I didn't found answer for my question in swiftbook.

Is this possible to create property-like closure for local variable in swift? I mean smt like further snippet:

```
 func someFunc() {
    // here goes our closure
    var myRect:CGRect {
        var x = 10
        var y = 20
        var width = 30
        var heigth = 40
    myRect = CGPointMake(x,y,width,heigth)
    }
}
```

I have complexity evaluation of UI elements position. This trick should make my code much readable

Comment: what is the purpose of it? it is just extra code and has no benefit whatsoever! Create utility functions if your one method gets to big.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is called read-only computed property where you can omit the getter to simplify declaration:

```
var myRect: CGRect {
    let x:CGFloat = 10
    let y:CGFloat = 20
    let width:CGFloat = 30
    let height:CGFloat = 40
    return CGRectMake(x, y, width, height)
}
```

> Read-Only Computed Properties
>
> A computed property with a getter but no setter is known as a
>   read-only computed property. A read-only computed property always
>   returns a value, and can be accessed through dot syntax, but cannot be
>   set to a different value.
>
> NOTE
>
> You must declare computed properties—including read-only computed
>   properties—as variable properties with the var keyword, because their
>   value is not fixed. The let keyword is only used for constant
>   properties, to indicate that their values cannot be changed once they
>   are set as part of instance initialization.
>
> You can simplify the declaration of a read-only computed property by
>   removing the get keyword and its braces:

[Documentation Swift Conceptual Properties](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Properties.html)

Comment: Properties didn't fit for my situation. I have a lot of views, I Can't store all of CGRect I need

Comment: @O.G.O I think you didn't understand how to use it. It works exactly the same as the other answer you just need to call it without ( )

Comment: Yeah. I've made few experiments and you totally right. I should to change correct answer as you was first. Sorry for misunderstanding

Answer (score 1):

Why not try this way?

```
fun someFunc() {
    var myRect = {() -> CGRect in
        let x:CGFloat = 10.0
        let y:CGFloat = 20.0
        let width:CGFloat = 30.0
        let height:CGFloat = 40.0
        return CGRectMake(x,y,width,height)
       }

    myRect() //Call it
}
```

**EDIT** I think if there are some requirements to calculate some points position like `maxElement` use closure is good to save some small functions.

Comment: Well, I can avoid using local property at all to set frame for UIView. Thank you for this answer

Comment: I think if need calculate many positions this way is good to reduce some small functions, but for the example on the question, seems no need in this way.

Comment: Leo was first and he's answer a lil bit closer to question. I have to give that mark to him. Sorry bout that. Anyway I've upvoted your answer too